# i am getting out of memory exception error

Tags: android

I am getting error - an out of memory exception at run time. How solve it?

```
public void next(View v)
   {
      Toast.makeText(this,"Next page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent i=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
       startActivity(i);
   }
```

XML is:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/save"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Comment: Add the stack trace in the code. Also post the class `Main2Activity`

Comment: Although you seem to have posted a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example it is very unlikely that this contains your problem. An out of memory exception is exactly what itsays, your code uses more memory than the operating system can provide. And that place in your code is not this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Big size image in your **drawable folder** you will get  error like `out of memory exception error` So kindly remove your Image from your drawable folder try it once.